# Shopify Help - Javascript Cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, shopify, liquid

It seems shopify stores cookies on your computer regarding the contents of your cart and it stores them for two weeks. Can anyone help with how to change this?

I have two options:
1) I make the shopping members only and the cart clears once the customer logs out if they have not purchased anything but added things to their cart.  (My preferred option)

2) Alternatively, the cookies either get deleted on browser close or within 24 hours but preferred is option 1.

Any ideas on how I can code it so the cart clears once customer logs out.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Capture the logout event. Before you actually execute the logout, simply clear the cart using the JSON API call to do that. That way any returning customer has nothing in the cart the next time they login.